# DirectShow Library-How to capture image using directshow library without showing the webcam live images on the PictureBox or Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, directshow, directshow.net

I am using WPF application which is using DirectShow library and it is working fine for grabbing images or recording the live feed,but i wants that end user should not be able to see that any web cam is taking their picture i.e. i wants picture box or panel which is rendering the feed from the webcam should not be visible to the user and i should be able to capture the images or record the live feed.

Please provide me any link or suggestion as i am beginner for the DirectShow library.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectShow does not need any visual component to grab snapshots or video. It is just one of the popular methods to display video live and grabs snapshots off the video presenter.

Read on using Sample Grabber to capture frames, and `DxSnap` sample from DirectShow.NET shows you how.

> Use DirectShow to take snapshots from the Still pin of a capture 
>   device.  Note the MS encourages you to use WIA for this, but if  you
>   want to do in with DirectShow and C#, here's how.
>
> Note that this sample will only work with devices that output
>   uncompressed video as RBG24.  This will include most webcams, but
>   probably zero tv tuners.

See also: [Best DirectShow way to capture image from web cam preview ? SampleGrabber is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398758/best-directshow-way-to-capture-image-from-web-cam-preview-samplegrabber-is-dep)